# How to get Country Code from (intl-tel-input) plugin after submitting the form?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms

I've installed the plugin and Its displaying the countries correctly and working fine, but when I submit the form that has the input of type = "tel", the form does not submit the country code, I don't know how this works, but I did read all of instructions in https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input page, but I didn't understand how to get the full number + code country together so I can insert them into MySQL data base.

I'm so beginner, and just confused how to get this to work fine.
Sorry if the question is not that hard, but I really don't know how this works.

The jQuery code I have:-

```
$("#telephone").intlTelInput({ 
    initialCountry: "sd",
    separateDialCode: true 
});
```

Comment: Get familiar with your browsers javascript debugger (F12 normally). Then read the Documentation on github and play with it a bit

Comment: When you get the number, put it in an <input> field in your form, maybe a hidden one if you like. Then it will get sent to the script when you submit

Comment: Just went on to see the github demo and if the HTML produced for you is the same, then maybe something like `$(".country[class*='active']").attr("data-dial-code")` should give you the dial code for the country that's been selected. You'll have to pass that variable manually using submit then. Or append before the string the value obtained here to the telephone number being sent to PHP.

Comment: @DhruvSaxena
can you please teach me how to append the (data-dial-code) to the phone number input:

<input type="tel" name="telephone" id="telephone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number">

I used append jQuery function but its not working!

Comment: Well, to be honest, this is just a quick fix that may not be very elegant or ideal. I don't how your form is being submitted, so can't really say much. However, what this does is: it appends the country code before the phone number value just as soon as the focus is taken away from the field: `$("#telephone").on("blur", function(){ 
 $(this).val("+" + $(".country[class*='active']").attr("data-dial-code") + $(this).val()); 
});` . If someone goes back to this field again and then leaves it (with or without editing), then it will once again cause the country code to be appended.

Comment: Well, I guess that's okay, I fixed the issue of the value being append again by adding condition :
`if($(this).val() == '') { // code }`

Comment: Thank you very much for the very helpful information...

Answer (score 16):

**intlTelInput option:**

**hiddenInput**

Add a hidden input with the given name. Alternatively, if your input name contains square brackets (e.g. name="phone_number[main]") then it will give the hidden input the same name, replacing the contents of the brackets with the given name (e.g. if you init the plugin with hiddenInput: "full", then in this case the hidden input would have name="phone_number[full]"). On submit, it will automatically populate the hidden input with the full international number (using getNumber). This is a quick way for people using non-Ajax forms to get the full international number, even when nationalMode is enabled. Avoid this option when using Ajax forms and instead just call getNumber to get the full international number to send in the request. Note: requires the input to be inside a form element, as this feature works by listening for the submit event on the closest form element. Also note that since this uses getNumber internally, firstly it requires the utilsScript option, and secondly it expects a valid number and so should only be used after validation.

```js
var phone_number = window.intlTelInput(document.querySelector("#phone_number"), {
  separateDialCode: true,
  preferredCountries:["in"],
  hiddenInput: "full",
  utilsScript: "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.3/js/utils.js"
});

$("form").submit(function() {
  var full_number = phone_number.getNumber(intlTelInputUtils.numberFormat.E164);
$("input[name='phone_number[full]'").val(full_number);
  alert(full_number)
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.3/css/intlTelInput.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.3/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="tel" name="phone_number[main]" id="phone_number" />
    <button type="submit" name="save">Save</button>
  </form>

</body>
```

**Php Code**

You can get full number like

```
$phone_number = $_REQUEST['phone_number']['full'];
```

Comment: var full_number = $(".iti__selected-dial-code").text();
            alert(full_number)

Comment: You must need to use  utils.js script then you will get full number

"//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.3/js/utils.js"

Comment: shouldnt $phone_number = $_REQUEST['full']; without ['phone_number']  be enough? - just asking

Answer (score 3):

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden"  id="code" name ="code" value="1" >
    <input type="text" id="phone" name ="phone" value="" >
    <button type="submit" >Send Verification Text</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#phone").intlTelInput({
            preferredCountries: ["us", "ca"],
            separateDialCode: true,
            initialCountry: ""
        }).on('countrychange', function (e, countryData) {
            $("#code").val(($("#phone").intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData").dialCode));

        });


    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

They have a function already. This will return something like this.

**phoneInput.getSelectedCountryData();**

{
name: "Afghanistan (‫افغانستان‬‎)",
iso2: "af",
dialCode: "93"
}

Comment: perfect, it works  `phoneInput.getSelectedCountryData()['dialCode']`

Answer (score 2):

Submit the form with this:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="post">
  <div class="select">
    <input type="hidden" id="phone2" name="phone"/>
    <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone-full">
  </div>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $("#phone2").val($("#phone").intlTelInput("getNumber"));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Searching a bit in the link you posted I found a [nice example](https://intl-tel-input.com/node_modules/intl-tel-input/examples/gen/country-sync.html) doing what you're asking

Taking some inspiration from the example, here is the code

HTML

```
<form action="post">
  <div class="select">
    <input type="hidden" id="country" name="country"/>
    <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone">
  </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
var input = $('#phone');
var country = $('#country');
var iti = intlTelInput(input.get(0))

// listen to the telephone input for changes
input.on('countrychange', function(e) {
  // change the hidden input value to the selected country code
  country.val(iti.getSelectedCountryData().iso2);
});
```

Comment: this like worked for me instead of `country.val(iti.getSelectedCountryData().iso2);` I used `$("#code").val(($("#phone").intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData").dialCode));`

Answer (score 0):

// Add code in intlTelInput.js to use current location show code

```
$currentCountry = 'us';
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://ip-api.com/json/',
        async: false,
        success:function(data){
            $currentCountry = data.countryCode.toLowerCase();
            // console.log(data.countryCode.toLowerCase());
        }
    })

    $selected = $('.country_code').attr('country_iso_code2') != undefined ? $('.country_code').attr('country_iso_code2') : $currentCountry;
    // console.log($selected);
    var pluginName = "intlTelInput", defaults = {
        preferredCountries: [ $selected ],
        // united states and united kingdom
        initialDialCode: true,
        americaMode: false,
        onlyCountries: []
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
(ng2TelOutput)="getNumberCellNo1($event)"
```

Javascript

```
getNumberCellNo1(e:any)
  {
    this.cell_code1.setNumber(e) 
    this.cellnumber1=e
  }
```

The `getNumber()` will give you the country code and number as +919843133490.
The `setNumber` will set the country flag and place the number inn input field.

Hope it helped. Any further queries can be asked.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML CODE**
Use this html code

```
<input type="text" name="ccode" id="ccode">
<input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" >
```

**JAVA SCRIPT CODE**

```
 //Country code

var titilec=title.split(":");
document.getElementById('ccode').value=titilec[1];
```

Add the above js code in your intlTelInput.js file after the below code

// update the selected country's title attribute

```
var title = countryCode ? "".concat(this.selectedCountryData.name, ": +").concat(this.selectedCountryData.dialCode) : "Unknown";
  this.selectedFlag.setAttribute("title", title);
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input type="tel" name="phone" class="phone-inteltel" required>
```

**Javascript**

```
 var input = document.querySelector(".phone-inteltel");
 window.intlTelInput(input, {
   separateDialCode: true,
   initialCountry: "auto",
   hiddenInput: "phone",
   geoIpLookup: function (callback) {
     $.get('https://ipinfo.io', function () { }, "jsonp").always(function (resp) {
       var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "tr";
       callback(countryCode);
     });
   },
   utilsScript: "https://intl-tel-input.com/node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/utils.js?1638200991544" // just for formatting/placeholders etc
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one liner to access the full number.

```
`+${$("#mobileno").intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData").dialCode} ${$("#mobileno").val()}`;
```

Answer (score -1):

For getting country short code and dial code add below lines(hidden inputs) inside the `<form>`,

```
<input type="hidden" name="dialCode" id="dialCode">
<input type="hidden" name="countryCode" id="countryCode">
```

Add below `javascript` code

```
$('.iti__country-list li').click(function(){
  $("#dialCode").val($(this).data('dial-code'));
  $("#countryCode").val($(this).data('country-code-code'));
})
```

Here, you are getting dial code and country short code string in the hidden inputs when the code is selected from the dropdown.

And after the form submitting, concatenate the dial code and mobile number to save in the database.